# remove duplicate across foreach loop

Tags: php

In my result I have some duplicate content inside my dropdown. Do you know how to resolve it?

Bu an `array_unique` ?

thank you

example :

```
<select name="boxtal_operator" id="sortDropDownListByText" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">--- Select ---</option>
    <option value="CHRP-1456S">AGAY / L'ATELIER FLORAL D'AGAY / 125 BD DE LA PLAGE / CHRP-1456S</option>
    <option value="CHRP-1456S">AGAY / L'ATELIER FLORAL D'AGAY / 125 BD DE LA PLAGE / CHRP-1456S</option>
    <option value="CHRP-1456S">AGAY / L'ATELIER FLORAL D'AGAY / 125 BD DE LA PLAGE / CHRP-1456S</option>
    <option value="SOGP-I3171">AGAY / PROXI / 1318 BD DE LA 36EME DI DU TEXASLE DRAMONT / SOGP-I3171</option>
    <option value="SOGP-I3171">AGAY / PROXI / 1318 BD DE LA 36EME DI DU TEXASLE DRAMONT / SOGP-I3171</option>
    <option value="SOGP-I3171">AGAY / PROXI / 1318 BD DE LA 36EME DI DU TEXASLE DRAMONT / SOGP-I3171</option>
</select>
```

below the php code allow to make this result.

```
$operator_code = ['POFR', 'MONR', 'SOGP', 'Chrono', 'CHRP', 'IMXE', 'UPSE', 'PUNT'];

$result_carrier_code[] = ['id' => '0', 'text' => Core::getDef('text_select')];

    foreach ($operator_code as $operator)
    {
        $list_point = $this->boxtaleShop->getListPoint($country_iso, $code_postal, $city, $operator);

        foreach ($list_point as $carrier)
        {
            if (is_array($carrier)) {
                foreach ($carrier as $item)
                {
                    if (is_array($item['points'])) {
                        foreach ($item['points'] as $points)
                        {
                            if (is_array($points)) {
                                $result_carrier_code[] = [
                                    'id' => $points['code'],
                                    'text' => $points['city'] . ' / ' . $points['name'] . ' / ' . $points['address'] . ' / ' . $points['code']
                                ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Array example (it's a big)

```
array(496) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "0" ["text"]=> string(14) "--- Select ---" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-08915" ["text"]=> string(57) "FREJUS / CULTURE INDOOR / ROUTE DE MALPASSET / MONR-08915" } [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-06124" ["text"]=> string(57) "FREJUS / CULTURE INDOOR / ROUTE DE MALPASSET / MONR-06124" } [3]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-05847" ["text"]=> string(63) "FREJUS / OLI'VAP / 2040 RUE DES COMBATTANTS D'AFRI / MONR-05847" } [4]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-03415" ["text"]=> string(79) "BAGNOLS EN FORET / CARREFOUR CONTACT / DEPARTEMENTAL 4 LA ROUVIERE / MONR-03415" } [5]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-05850" ["text"]=> string(53) "FREJUS / SOS PHONE / 169 RUE JEAN JAURES / MONR-05850" } [6]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-94030" ["text"]=> string(88) "FREJUS / FITNESS BOUTIQUE FREJUS / 129 RUE ALERT EINSTEIN, FACE A DAFY MOTO / MONR-94030" } [7]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-99539" ["text"]=> string(75) "SAINT-RAPHAEL / WELDOM ST RAPHAEL / 1205 BOULEVARD JEAN MOULIN / MONR-99539" } [8]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-04322" ["text"]=> string(78) "ST RAPHAEL / AVADI BOUTIQUE CADEAU / 80 AVENUE DU GENERAL LECLERC / MONR-04322" } [9]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-03980" ["text"]=> string(68) "ST RAPHAEL / PHARMACIE DES GENETS / 1416 BD JEAN MOULIN / MONR-03980" } [10]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-03457" ["text"]=> string(55) "FREJUS / COLOR-LAB / 229 RUE ROLAND GARROS / MONR-03457" } [11]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-63070" ["text"]=> string(73) "PUGET SUR ARGENS / AGENCE MONDIAL RELAY / 577 BD DU COMMERCE / MONR-63070" } [12]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-04715" ["text"]=> string(92) "FREJUS / MINERAUX & MERVEILLES / 362 RUE VICTOR REYBAUD, SQUARD LIBERATION PARK / MONR-04715" } [13]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-12297" ["text"]=> string(60) "FREJUS / TABAC PRESSE / 355 RUE HIPPOLYTE FABRE / MONR-12297" } [14]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(10) "MONR-04478" ["text"]=> string(61) "STRAPHAEL / EPICERIE / 144 BD GEORGES CLEMENCEAU / MONR-04478" }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Duplicates in Foreach Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53647873/removing-duplicates-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: @MateusMartins If I try this : it' does'nt work :  $result_carrier_code = array_unique($result_carrier_code);

Comment: Show us the array and we can help you, as it is now it's hard to help

Comment: @Andreas : Doe. It's a big, you have an example

Comment: I'm not going to guess an answer. Either you show us the array or part of the array or I just vote to close the question. You should probably go visit the help section and read how to ask a question.